# LINQ to SQL Basic column search doing OR / AND of a List<string> (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, linq

Is there a way to check if a column contains all or any of an items in a list?   Example  "ABCDEFG"  is my column value.  "A" "C" "L" is my list stored in a list.  I need to find rows that contains at least one item in my list.  Then items that contains ALL the items in my list (a basic OR / AND search such as a SE would have)

Note I am using VB.net, not C#

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq2Sql doesn't support many methods on `String` type. Which makes sense if you recall that your linq code is going to be translated to SQL.

The best option here would be to have a table on the server to contain your list and then write an SQL query.

Otherwise, you'd need to leave Linq2Sql area and only use the Linq part. That is, select all data to the client and then filter:

```
Dim letter_list = New List(Of String)(New String() {"A", "C", "L"})

Using d = New DataClasses1DataContext

    Dim contains_any = (From f In d.footest _
                       Select f).ToList().Where(Function(f) f.v IsNot Nothing AndAlso f.v.Any(Function(c) letter_list.Contains(c))).ToList()

    Dim contains_all = (From f In d.footest _
                       Select f).ToList().Where(Function(f) f.v IsNot Nothing AndAlso letter_list.All(Function(s) f.v.Contains(s))).ToList()


End Using
```

Comment: Neither option is really possible. There can be up to a million rows and the list is dynamic by search.  Because of this I am dynamically generating the query and just going to use my entity.executestoredcommand.  Thanks though!

Comment: @AnthonyGreco Then consider [full text search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx). [`CONTAINS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) is what you want. You can easily make a server-side function for searching and call that with linq.

Comment: GSerg: The problem with CONTAINS is it will only do 1 item, not multiple items.  I can do where column.contains(a) AND column.contains(b), however if the amount of items i need to search is not static, I can't see that working

Comment: @AnthonyGreco `CONTAINS` can do many items as well. See example D in the documentation. You will only have to construct the query string at the client side (such as `'"A" OR "C" OR "L"'`) and then pass it to the server.